# What is the use of this remove before flight cover on the nose of a Bombardier Global 6000?

Tags: avionics, private-jets, bombardier

I recently saw a Bombardier Global 6000 at my local airport. I was just wondering what the use of this circled remove before flight cover on the nose of the Bombardier Global 6000 is. I never saw such covers before on a aircraft. What is the cover covering and why are the 3 ones connected with a wire?

[image: ![Picture of a Bombardier Global 6000]

([Own work](http://www.jetphotos.net/photo/8417782))

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I shamelessly lifted your photo for another question.

Comment: No problem if you mention the source.

Comment: I did. Nice photo BTW

Comment: Here is the jetphotos.net url: http://www.jetphotos.net/photo/8417782

Comment: yes I would like this too

Comment: My question was: What's under the circled remove before flight cover and why are they 3 remove bevore flight strips connected with a wire?

Comment: I know what this things are. I just want to know the circled things.

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These covers are used to keep foreign objects away and out of the air data sensors, pitot tubes, static ports and Angle of Attack sensors (large red covers) while the aircraft is resting on the ground.  Blockage or damage to these sensors by foreign objects prevents the aircraft flight control computers and instruments from collecting accurate data and could be disastrous in flight, especially in instrument conditions.  The wires are essentially a leash to hold the neoprene covers together in a group and both prevent their loss during storage and ensure that all covers are removed from the sensors during pre-flight.

Comment: I know the use of remove before flight covers but the question refers to the big one in the middle and why are they connected with a wire? I've just edited the question.

Comment: I've just added the circles to the image.

Comment: In my opinion, the pitot tubes are right underneath the circle. It looks way to big for pitot tubes from my point of view.

Comment: Those are heated AOA sensors

Comment: And they are covered like this, that nobody can move them?

Comment: No just to preven them from being bumped into or damaged during ground towing, hangaring, etc.

Comment: @PascalAckermann To learn what can happen if you _don't_ cover these, see [Birgenair Flight 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birgenair_Flight_301).

Comment: Better yet, [XL Airways flight 888T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XL_Airways_Germany_Flight_888T?wprov=sfla1)