# What are these hooks and tassels on the nose?

Tags: feature-identification, nose

What are the hooks and tassels hanging down from the nose of this aircraft?

[image: Aircraft with hooks]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is Brisbane airport (YBBN). Brisbane has a notorious problem with wasps building nests inside the tubes so much quicker than at other airports, so these covers are put on even for short turnarounds.

Comment: LoL. Thanks, Ben.

Comment: Related: [Air data system failure involving Airbus A330-243, A6-EYJ, near Brisbane Airport](https://www.atsb.gov.au/publications/investigation_reports/2013/aair/ao-2013-212/)

Answer (score 19):

The things hanging on the left and right side of the nose are **pitot covers**. They cover the pitot tubes located here:

[image: Pitot Tubes]

<sup>([Boeing 737 Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning](https://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/airports/acaps/737.pdf))</sup>

The covers are there to protect the narrow inlets from contamination or blockage:

> Pitot tubes are normally covered when the aircraft is parked for more than a short period of time to reduce the chance of blockage or contamination.

<sup>([Pitot Static System on SYKbrary](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Pitot_Static_System))</sup>

They are usually painted red and have **REMOVE BEFORE FLIGHT** written on them:

[image: 737 Pitot Covers]

<sup>([aircraftcovers.com](https://www.aircraftcovers.com/media/images/12119.jpg))</sup>

Related:

- [What is the use of this remove before flight cover on the nose of a Bombardier Global 6000?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33375/what-is-the-use-of-this-remove-before-flight-cover-on-the-nose-of-a-bombardier-g)
- [What steps have been taken to rule out instrument failure due to blocked static ports or pitot tubes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22137/what-steps-have-been-taken-to-rule-out-instrument-failure-due-to-blocked-static/37875#37875)

---

The cable connected to the right side of the aircraft (left on your image) is the **ground power** cable. You can see it larger in this image:

[image: 737 Ground Power]

<sup>([pinterest.com](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/714665034589878535/))</sup>

Related:

- [What is the cable connected to a plane for?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9676/what-is-the-cable-connected-to-a-plane-for)
- [What powers an aircraft prior to the APU being switched on?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70268/what-powers-an-aircraft-prior-to-the-apu-being-switched-on)
- [What's the plug used on airliners for ground power?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70301/whats-the-plug-used-on-airliners-for-ground-power)

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks!! 